# После каждого элемента вставить в массив элемент, равный сумме предыдущих элементов

Tags: c++

У меня есть задание: После каждого элемента вставить в массив элемент, равный сумме предыдущих элементов.
Например изначальный массив {1,2,3,4,5}
Должен получится такой массив {1,1,2,3,3,6,4,10,5,15}
Я знаю как посчитать сумму. Но как вставить эту сумму в массив?

Comment: сделайте новый массив двойной длины

Comment: это я понял, но как понять куда нужно вставлять сумму?

Comment: ну у вас же в новом массиве будут чередоваться значения из старого массива и соответствующие значения сумм. Вот и сделайте цикл от ```0``` до ```2*n - 1``` с шагом ```2```, если ```n``` - размер начального массива и пишите на каждом шаге в ```i``` и ```i+1``` элементы

Comment: цикл сделать с помощь while?

Comment: В нечётные индексы  for(i=0..n-1){B[2*i]=A[i];sum = ...; B[2*i+1]=sum}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, для вашего массива из 5 элементов.

```
int main() {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int* b = new int[size(a) * 2];
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size(a); ++i) {
        b[j++] = a[i];
        sum += a[i];
        b[j++] = sum;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * size(a); ++i)
        cout << b[i] << " ";
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!